# How to make sure Python write the entire set of data in a .dat file?

Tags: python

Good morning,
I'm trying to write a list of nonces I randomly generate in a .dat file so I can use them without memory issues. For that, I use the following code:

```
n=open("nonces.dat", "w")
for i in range(17000):
     nonce_bits2=''
     for j in range(128):
        nonce_bits2+=str(random.randint(0,1))
     n.write(nonce_bits2)
     n.write("\n")
```

However, when I open my file after the code has run, I only get 16960 nonces instead of 17000.
When I go for 20000, I get 19968 instead.
Do you know what could be the issue here please ?

Comment: You aren't closing your file which may cause some issues. Also "nonce" means something different where I'm from

Comment: Thank you very much ! That totally worked ! Sorry I should have specified this was the crypto version of nonce ^^.